# What is the function for an arch given its height and base?

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

Given:

1. The arch is symmetrical about the y axis.
2. The base of the arch is on the x axis.
3. At the top of the arch: $$ x = 0; y = h$$
4. At the ends of the arch $$ y = 0; x = \pm \frac{b}{2} $$
5. An arch is an arc, the two base points and the top of the arch fit on a circle.

What is the function for the arch?

Comment: Any even function $f$ such that $f(0)=h$ and $f(\pm0.5)=0$ satisfied conditions. Do you have any other condition?

Comment: There are infinitely many even functions whose max is at $(0,h)$ and which passes through $(\pm b/2, 0)$.

Comment: I am assuming an arch is an arc.  The top points and the two end points are on a circle with an unknown radius

Comment: I found some information on a [sagitta] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_%28geometry%29.)   I think this would refer to the height.

Comment: Do you mean that the entire arch is some section of a circle?  So that the answer provided by @Bye_World provides an approach to obtaining the center and radius of said circle?

Comment: Yes! I agree with statement.

Comment: If you suppose only first fourth conditions, and assume $f\in C^1$ and at each $t\in[0,b/2]$, you now the arc lenght of arc joining points $(0,h)$ and $(b/2,0)$. That is, $F:[0,b/2]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $F(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{1+f^\prime(x)^2}dx$ is known. Then $f^\prime(t)=\sqrt{F^\prime(x)^2-1}$. Integring both sides from 0 to $x$ give us $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x\sqrt{F^\prime(t)^2-1}dt$. Then $f(x)=h+\int_0^x\sqrt{F^\prime(t)^2-1}dt$ for all $x\in[0,b/2]$, and it can be extend to all $[-b/2,b/2]$ in order to obtain $f$.

Comment: Circular Arch, Parabolic Arch or Centenary Arch?

Comment: sinbadh - Thanks for pointing out I had an unclear condition on this problem.  The function I asked about is being used to describe the cross section of a fresh compost pile when it is mounded in a long row.  For some reason for which I am unsure, the fresh natural piling I am observing approximates an arch. Geometry is all I needed. It would be interesting to see if the integral approach could be used to model the collapse of a row as composting took place.  F(t) is related to the amount of material in the row.

Comment: ja - Please forgive my ignorance of those terms.  If you can define those terms or point me to a link which does I'll do my best to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the function should be a part of a circle.  OK.  Let's start frm there.  The equation of a circle is $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$.  You have three points on this circle.  Let's try using those three points to solve for $x_0$, $y_0$, and $r$.

First thing is that it being symmetrical about the $y$-axis means that $x_0=0$.  That simplifies things a bit.  Then

$$\begin{array}{lr}(0)^2+(h-y_0)^2=r^2 \iff |h-y_0|=r \implies h-y_0 = r & \text{(because $(0,h)$ is max)} \\ (\pm b/2)^2+(0-y_0)^2=r^2 \iff b^2/4 + {y_0}^2=r^2\end{array}$$

So you've got the system $$\begin{cases} r+y_0 = h \\ r^2-{y_0}^2=b^2/4\end{cases}$$

Notice that $r^2-{y_0}^2 = (r-y_0)(r+y_0) = (r-y_0)h$

Thus you have $$\begin{cases} r+y_0 = h \\ r-y_0=b^2/4h\end{cases}$$

Solving this gives us $r=\frac 12(h+b^2/4h)$ and $y_0 = \frac 12(h-b^2/4h)$

Thus your circle is $$x^2+\left(y-\frac 12(h-b^2/4h)\right)^2=\left(\frac 12(h+b^2/4h)\right)^2$$

Now just restrict the domain of this so that it's only the part of the circle you want and you're done.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the piece I was missing.

Comment: No problem.$\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there are an infinite number of such functions, e.g.:$$y=h\left(\frac{2}{b}\right)^{2n}\left(\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^{2n}-x^{2n}\right)$$for $n=1,2,\cdots$

---

Since you changed the question to state that the arch must be a circle, then, since this circle is symmetrical about the y-axes it's center must lie on the y-axes, thus you need to solve:$$x^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$to find $y_0$ and $r$ given the known points.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the function for the *arch*?

One of the simplest examples I can think of is an ellipse with centre in $(0,0)$, $x$-semiaxis of lenght $\dfrac{|b|}{2}$ and $y$-semiaxis of lenght $h$. In that case the equation you're looking for would be:
$$ \dfrac{4x^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{h^2} = 1,\quad y \geq 0.$$

For example for $|b| = 8$ and $h = 5$ you'd have:
$$ \dfrac{x^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{25} = 1,\quad y \geq 0,$$
which is the equation of the upper part of the curve shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working directly with the equation of the circle is pretty straightforward for this problem. Here's a slightly different approach that can lead to simpler calculations in other circumstances.

Perpendicular bisectors of chords of a circle meet at its center, so finding the center of the circle amounts to solving a pair of simultaneous linear equations.

In this case, one of the bisectors is the $y$-axis and the other two are easily found to be $$
{y-\frac h2\over x-\frac b4}=\frac b{2h}
\text{ and }
{y-\frac h2\over x+\frac b4}=-\frac b{2h}.
$$ Substituting $x=0$ into either of these and solving for $y$ gives $y_0=\frac12\left(h-\frac{b^2}{4h}\right)$ for the circle’s center and $h-y_0=\frac12\left(h+\frac{b^2}{4h}\right)$ for its radius.